# Why is there a lot of CPU usage on mostly IO operation?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, ext3

I have a process writing binary files into ext3 filesystem.

I would assume that this should be a pretty easy process on CPU, but I see 45% system CPU utilization. It's a 40-cores 80-threads server, and there is a RAID 1+0 16 disks array.

There are 100 threads doing IO at the same time. Is this normal to have almost half of system CPU used? Is there a way to analyze why it is using so much of the CPU?

User CPU is around 10-15%.

The process is like this: we read some data from a file, check if the data is in db, then we write the data into files. Db is on different machine, logging is also on a different machine.
What happens is we check if the file is already there, it is usually not there, so we create a new file and write some data into it.

here is what I see with

iostat -xkt 1

```
03/07/2014 01:06:28 PM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          16.14    0.00   43.24    0.01    0.00   40.60

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb               0.00   166.00    0.00   69.00     0.00   940.00    27.25     0.02    0.23   0.17   1.20
sda               0.00   322.00    1.00  598.00   128.00  3680.00    12.71     0.07    0.12   0.09   5.50
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-3              0.00     0.00    0.00  235.00     0.00   940.00     8.00     0.06    0.26   0.05   1.10
dm-4              0.00     0.00    1.00  920.00   128.00  3680.00     8.27     0.10    0.11   0.06   5.40
```

Comment: You would have to benchmark the code.

Comment: This is not my code, so I can't do much about it.

Comment: If you cannot benchmark the code then you cannot determine the cause of the CPU usage.

Comment: Where do the "binary files" come from? Hardware or software RAID? Any other activity on the machine?

Comment: I added more info in the end. It is hardware RAID. We do some logging on diff. file system and there is also database on different computer

Answer (score 1):

Linux's load averaging, and some load monitors (top) will show io-wait as load.

Basically, when the CPU is waiting on the IO device (and not processing other load) it is still considered "loaded" and therefore contributes to load averages.

Comment: I used iostat -xkt 1 to get the stats, I added the results to the question. There is very little iowait